# How to translate labels for contact page on multi-language site?

Tags: joomla-3.6, template-override, multilingual, translation, contact

I'm working on a multi-lingual joomla 3.6 site and I'm running into a problem with the contact page. The issue I'm running into is how to internationalize the labels on the contact page corresponding to the active language menu.

I'm using the core contact component, mapped to both the German and an English Menus. I want to show the same contact information, but with language appropriate labels for "Address" and "Miscellaneous Information" to the language appropriate equivalents. I have looked into creating a separate display layout, but it looks like the com_contact html files use hard-coded variables for the labels I want to change. I'm looking into Language Overrides, but I'm not sure how to limit them to pages on the German menu.

#### Update:

The problem I have comes down to that not all of the content labels are translated.

[image: langauge issues] The Contact form is translated, but the labels for Address, Phones, and Miscellaneous Information remain in English. I guess my question comes down to how to I make language specific changes to those labels.

Comment: What is the standard contact module?

Comment: com_contact, the core module.

Comment: there is no such core module - do mean the component?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean. I assumed it was a core module...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your additional language pack should contain your language's translations for the translatable strings of the labels.

- Simply create your GER and ENG contacts in the contact manager, in the same manner as you do for your other content.
- Create menu items in both your ENG / GER menus, set their language and select the corresponding contact.

You should be ok.

#### Update:

I just tested the de-DE language pack and the single contact menu item is translated. If you have done all of the required steps to produce a multi-lingual contact page but you still get english translations, then maybe check your template's html overrides, as it might ships with an override for the contact page that contains no Translatable strings.

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed that myself today, however in looking at the com_contact html, I noticed that the strings that it's pulling in are TPL_CONTACT_ADDRESS and TPL_CONTACT_PHONES, which don't appear in the list of string overrides. As I said above most of the text is translated, just a handful of these don't seem to be affected. Also, my template only has one language pack in it's folder, so I don't know if that's affecting the situation as well...

Comment: So, I how do I check for html overrides? I can see that the template only has one language pack installed which may play a role in all this. and I've confirmed that all the strings are in the translation, so I'm guess it has to be something to do with the template itself.

Comment: I think I've stumbled on it. The template only has one language pack, which seems to have all the strings I want translated in it. I will mess around with creating a German language template pack, but this seems wrong somehow...

Comment: @nizz0k - so there is a template override for the contact page... As for just to confirm that this is actually the reason you don't see the german version - just rename the contact template override, refresh the page (clear any caches) and see if you get anything different in the front-end. After you confirm all these go ahead with whatever else you have to do to translate your pages. You can certainly create a german language for the template, or simply create language overrides for GER for those (TPL_CONTACT_ADDRESS, TPL_CONTACT_PHONES) translation strings in the backend.

Comment: it seems your question has been answered as of what you have to do to have multilingual contact pages and what was causing your issues. If you encounter other issues in the process of adding your own translations to your template, it won't be a good idea to keep coming with comments to this question, but it will be better to ask another question with those issues.